# Javascript Message Box in ASP.NET webapp

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, messagebox

I am using the code below to handle some exceptions in the webapp I'm building:

```
            Dim msg As String
            Dim SF_msg As String = "Please input lower bounds in SF Parameter Section"
            msg = "<script language = 'javascript'>"
            msg += "alert('" & SF_msg & "');"
            msg += "<" & "/script>"
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(msg)
```

The output of the code is a messagebox that apparently temporarily hides the page in order to show the message.

[image]

What I would like however is a javascript message box that stays on the page without hiding it. Something like the "confirm navigation" message in most webapps:

[image]

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a classic asp ?

Comment: this is .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: just check the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this one instead: (needs to be converted to VB)

> ```
>  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "confirm", 
>         "confirm('Please input lower bounds in SF Parameter Section');", true);
> ```